# Is there a difference between "mítad" and "mitad" as the Spanish word for "half" in English?

Tags: español-neutral, acentuación

Is there a difference between "mítad" and "mitad" as the Spanish word for "half" in English?

I have seen it written with both the `i` and the `í` (with an accent) and was  curious what the difference was, if any.

I see this from time to time on Twitter:

> Volar a Nigeria y en **mítad** del camino sobrevolar este punto tiene su
>   cosa...
>
> **Mítad** de semana y con mucha energía

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `mítad` does not exist as a word. It must be an error.

The pronunciation of the word "mitad" is done by stressing the "a". Thus, adding an accent to the "i" would make it sound differently, like a different word. And I have never heard this, [neither does the DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=mitad) mention another possibility.

So I think this is a mere typo that someone did when writing it.

---

[Your comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/is-there-a-difference-between-m%C3%ADtad-and-mitad-as-the-spanish-word-for-half/15061?noredirect=1#comment17328_15061) mentions two sentences where you saw the word written this way. One of them I could find in Twitter:

> Volar a Nigeria y en mítad del camino sobrevolar este punto tiene su
>   cosa... [source in Twitter](https://twitter.com/fjlopezm/status/503657122878734336)

The user says "mítad del camino", meaning "half way". But, as I said above, this word does not have an accent, so it is only the user who made a typo.

Comment: I see this from time to time on twitter.   e.g.,   Volar a Nigeria y en mítad del camino sobrevolar este punto tiene su cosa...   or Mítad de semana y con mucha energía

Comment: @drshock I found one of the sources. It is indeed a mistake and `mitad` without accent should be the answer. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

**Mìtad** doesn't exist as a word.  It's a mistake.  Just **mitad** that has the same meaning and is used in the same context as **half**.